# Tab bar text is too big after dismissing a modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my application I have a `TabBar` and a `ViewController` which is presented modally by using a DelegateProtocol. While everything is working as expected I receive a weird bug. When I dismiss my modal ViewController the labels of the TabBarItems are bigger than before. Even adjusting the size afterwards does not work.

I am dismissing my modal ViewController like this:

```
-(void)universalLoginFinished:(UniversalLoginModalViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"Login successful");
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.isLoggedIn = YES;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MerriweatherSans-Regular" size:18.0f], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
        [self.tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x0077B3)];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }];
}
```

**EDIT**

[image: My TabBar before calling and dismissing the modal view]

My TabBar before calling and dismissing the modal view

[image: My TabBar before calling and dismissing the modal view]

My TabBar after calling and dismissing the modal view

Do I forget something which causes my TabBarItems' labels to grow or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you add a screenshot ? also please explain why are you calling the viewdidload from a mthod ?

Comment: I am adding a screenshot in a second. I call it to reload my view after dismissing the modal view. [self.view setNeedsDisplay] did not work out for me.

Comment: the size 18 font ? is it what the previous font too ?

Comment: Yes I only use 18.0f as a size for the item's labels.

Comment: try make it 9 and see, it the label still expands. Im sure, it is related to size!!!

Comment: Neither making it 9 nor executing the TabBar size manipulation in the viewDidLoad I am calling solved the issue.. But changing the color is working properly, so the code is executed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying further tests I noticed that the font is responsible for the bigger labels. I use a custom font "MerriWeatherSans-Regular" which seems to be incompatible with the `[UIFont fontWithName:fontName]` method. After using "MerriWeatherSans" everything works as expected.

Although it is working now I feel quite confused because the "MerriWeatherSans-Regular" works in other `ViewControllers` in my app.

Just for completeness here is my final code:

```
-(void)universalLoginFinished:(UniversalLoginModalViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"Login successful");
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.isLoggedIn = YES;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MerriweatherSans" size:18.0f], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x0077B3)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set font size 18.0, thats what it should look like. And it's not clear why it's necessary go Update tabbar appearance after dismissing your modal view controller and calling `ViewDidLoad`. I think if you set `completion:nil`, your problem will go away.

You could probably apply some better approach. Like You can write a method in your AppDelegate that loads `TabBarController` along with it's viewControllers. So, at first you'll present login screen as the RootViewController of your window, then after login is complete, you can just call the method to load the `TabBarController`from AppDelegate.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have changed my code according to the first part of your answer but it did not change the behaviour. My labels are still too big.